# How to create a Log in C++?

Tags: c++, logging

I want to print lots of debug log prints in C++. Is there a built-in library that will allow me to turn on/off these prints without commenting them out as I do today (i.e., let the user use a `-print_log`/`-debug` flag)?

**EDIT**: third party loggers will be welcomed.

Please include a short example of how to do this.

Comment: Doesn't every C++ programmer write his own One True Logger With Many Unnecessary Features once in his life? :)

Comment: see if log4cpp suits your needs

Comment: Simplest logging class, according to the author: http://ahm507.blogspot.com/2006/12/simplest-logging-class-in-c.html

Comment: I think laziness is probably the #1 best programmer quality.

Comment: @Kos, of course we do. I stopped with new features when I imagined a two-dimensional kind of log levels. One dimension is the severity of the log message (error, warning, info), and other is level of detail (normal, verbose, debug) that is attached to each segment of log message. I realized on time that I don't really need this.

Comment: @Sujith why not write an answer?

Comment: @Amir: Posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Boost, consider using the proposed [Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) library. It's not yet part of the official Boost release, but I've found it to be quite good. Manually integrating it into the Boost build process was a little challenging though.

Answer (score 4):

google glog is a good example

http://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest ACE but it includes cross platform functionality that wasn't asked for. glog at first glance looks great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [syslog](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Overview-of-Syslog.html)

Comment: Isn't this just Unix? The OP didn't say if he was on Unix or Windows

Answer (score 1):

One of approaches: write all messages to std::wclog.
It's similar to std::wcout and can be redirected in the same way.

Not sure about its multithread safety, or other features, but it seems to be the simplest way - it already exists.

Comment: What is `std::wcout`? What does writing to `std::wclog` do?

Comment: @Amir: Wide-Character OUTput.  wclog is the wide-character version of clog, which writes to the same place as cerr (without ios::unitbuf), which writes to standard error (stderr from C).

Answer (score 1):

log4cpp works really well.

There is a BOOST log although it is not part of the official set of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in library. There are third-party libraries, or you could implement your own without too much effort. One decent way to do this is to have a logging function that accepts a FILE*, that can be stdout or /dev/null (or equivalent), or a file, etc.

Since you mention that it's C++, you can also do it with streams, accepting an `ostream&` that can be cout, cerr, a file, etc.